# Accessing JSON element returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to print out a JSON element called `favColor`.  I can see that `favColor` is included in the `response.data`, but I can't access it using `response.data.favColor` for some reason.

If I print `response.data` to the console, I get the following:

`{"favColor":"green"}`

However, `response.data.favColor` returns `undefined`.

My form:

```
  <form>
      <label>Favorite Color: </label>
      <br>
      <input id="favColor" name="favColor" type="text">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit POST Data" id="submitPost">
  </form>
  <br>
  <div>
      <label>Favorite Color:</label>
      <div id=returnedFavColor></div>
  </div>
```

My Script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', post);

function post() {
    document.getElementById('submitPost').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var payload = {favColor: null};
        payload.favColor = document.getElementById('favColor').value;
        req.open("POST", "https://httpbin.org/post", true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.addEventListener('load',function(){
            if(req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400){
                var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                console.log(response.data);
                document.getElementById('favColor').textContent = response.data.favColor;
            } else {
                console.log("Error in network request: " + request.statusText);
            }
        });
        req.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: probably `response.data` is just a string with the value `{"favColor":"green"}`. You could log `console.log(typeof response.data);` to test this.

Comment: Agree with @wero  you may need to deserialize it.

Comment: *"Accessing JSON element returns undefined"* There is also a terminology issues here. "JSON" is a data exchange format, it's basically text, just like XML, YAML or CSV. In JavaScript, text can only exist of a part of a string (that's what `req.responseText` returns). When you parse the string containing JSON (`JSON.parse(...)`) you get back a JavaScript value, most often an *object* or an *array*. At that point you are not dealing with JSON anymore. Any issues with accessing the data are related to JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: @nurdyguy: *"deserializing the string back into JSON"* Surely you mean to an "object". JSON *is* the serialized form of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you double encoded your data. The very fact that the console output for `response.data` is `{"favColor":"green"}` proves  that it is a string (if it was an object, you would see something like `Object { ... }` instead).

You should fix that on the server side, so that your data doesn't contain nested JSON, and your code will work fine.

Comment: How would I go about fixing this on the server side?

Comment: Make sure you are only encoding the "top level" value as JSON (whatever holds the `data` property), not any other values. What *exactly* to do depends on your code of course.